# Is 'goto' smart for correct working with stack variables in C (not C++)

Tags: c

(Sorry for bad English.)

**Question 1.**

```
void foo(void)
{
    goto inside;
    for (;;) {
        int stack_var = 42;
inside:
        ...
    }
}
```

Will be a place in stack allocated for the `stack_var` when I goto the `inside` label? I.e. can I correctly use the `stack_var` variable within `...`?

**Question 2.**

```
void foo(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        int stack_var = 42;
        ...
        goto outside;
    }
outside:
    ...
}
```

Will be a place in stack of the `stack_var` deallocated when I goto the `outside` label? E.g. is it correct to do `return` within `...`?

In other words, is `goto` smart for correct working with stack variables (automatic (de)allocation when I walk through blocks), or it's just a stupid jump?

Comment: Just keep an eye out for raptors when compiling.

Comment: in C++, your second example is well defined (and the correct destructors will be called for more complex automatic variables). The first one, however has undefined behavior. I believe that in C, the only thing that will go wrong is that `stack_var` will not be correctly initialized in the first example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Question 1:

> can I correctly use the stack_var variable within ...?

The code in ... can write to `stack_var`. However, this variable is uninitialized because the execution flow jumped over the initialization, so the code should not read from it without having written to it first.

From the C99 standard, 6.8:3

> The initializers of objects that have automatic storage duration […] are evaluated and the values are stored in the objects (including storing an indeterminate value in objects without an initializer) each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution

My compiler compiles the function below to a piece of assembly that sometimes returns the uninitialized contents of `x`:

```
int f(int c){
  if (c) goto L;
  int x = 42;
 L:
  return x;
}

    cmpl    $0, %eax
    jne LBB1_2
    movl    $42, -16(%rbp)
LBB1_2:
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
...
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

### Question 2:

> Will be a place in stack of the stack_var deallocated when I goto the outside label?

Yes, you can expect the memory reserved for `stack_var` to be reclaimed as soon as the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but does this not imply that the variable will in fact be initialized?

Comment: @H2CO3 Both my compiler and I interpret the “each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution” as meaning that when the declaration is not reached in the order of execution, the initialization does not happen.

Comment: Just to clarify: the compiler _might_ do the initialisation nevertheless, it's not forbidden. Whenever the behaviour is defined, there won't be an observable difference; if the behaviour is undefined the compiler may do whatever anyway. So with optimisations turned on, gcc translates the above example correctly(1) to `movl $42, %eax; ret;`. (1) That's _one_ of the correct translations.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues:

- *lexical scoping* of variables inside *C* code. A *C* variable only makes sense inside the block in which it is declared. You could imagine that the compiler is renaming variables to unique names, which have sense only inside the scope block.
- *call frames* in the generated code. A good optimizing compiler usually allocate the call frame of the current function on the machine class stack at the beginning of the function. A given location in that call frame, called a *slot* can (and usually is) reused by the compiler for several local variables (or other purposes).

And a local variable can be kept in a register only (without any slot in the call frame), and that register will obviously be reused for various purposes.

You are probably hurting **undefined behavior** for your first case. After the `goto inside` the `stack_var` is uninitialized.

I suggest you to compile with `gcc -Wall` and to improve the code till no warnings are given.